# Find and wrap SPAN around all selected words in a DIV

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, regex

I have some predefined words and I want to find these words in a sentence and add a SPAN tag.

*For example;*

> Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting
>   industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever
>   since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and
>   scrambled it to make a type specimen book.

In this sentence I would like to add a `SPAM` label to the words:

**Words:**

- industry's standard
- 1500s
- specimen book

**`DOM` will be like this**

```
<div class="exampleArticle">
    Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has 
    been the <span id="marked">industry's standard</span> dummy text ever since the <span id="marked">1500s</span>, when an unknown 
    printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type <span id="marked">specimen book</span>.
</div>
```

Code:

```
$in = 'Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry\'s standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.';

    $words = array(
        "industry's standard", "1500s", "specimen book"
    ); 
    $wrap_before = '<span id="marked">';
    $wrap_after  = '</span>';

    $out = preg_replace("/($words)/i", "$wrap_before$1$wrap_after", $in);
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! We will be glad to help you if you get stuck on a *specific* programming problem, but we are not here to write code or design your system for you. You will need to at least make an attempt at solving your own issue. Please see [**How do I ask a good question?**](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [**What topics can I ask about here?**](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: @AlexHowansky I updated my question. You really fast for comment :)

Comment: You're on the right track. First hint -- don't use `preg_replace()` use `str_replace()`.

Comment: Your code works fine, look at @AlexHowansky `s suggestion to process all the words.

Comment: @AlexHowansky I used this `str_replace()` but nothing has changed I can not see the my mistake

Comment: @Nic Code is fine but not working. I can not see the my mistake

Comment: `preg_replace()` would work just fine if you put the regex pattern in the array, instead of trying to put the array in the regex (which, I imaginge, is throwing an error)

Comment: Then preg_replace cannot use an array as input for your pattern.  So a working solution is   "/($words[0])/".   str_replace() can use an array...

Comment: @PatrickQ Regex is great for like this problem but I dont have knowledge for Regex

Comment: @Nic Only work with `preg_replace`

Comment: Regex is not great for this problem, you don't need it because your search strings are well defined and static. If you use regex and happen to have any special regex chars (like `.` or `?`) in your search string, then the replacement will (most likely) fail.

Comment: @AlexHowansky Can it cause problems with quotation marks? For example: it is registered in the database in like this. `industry\'s standard` - maybe it can be prevented with Regex.. I think

Comment: @AlexHowansky To include the pattern text in the replacement with `str_replace()`, wouldn't you explicitly have to include it in the replacement list? I'm not aware of `str_replace()` using capture tokens. I'd love to know that I'm wrong though :)

Comment: `str_replace($search, $pre . $search . $post, $source);`

Comment: Note the search string is *not* a pattern. It's just a string.

Comment: Which works fine for a single word, but gets a bit out-of-hand with arrays, no?

Comment: `str_replace()` takes arrays as args just like `preg_replace()` does. Or use a loop. Or `array_walk()`. The `preg_replace()` alternative is that you'd have to make sure the search string is not actually regex by individually escaping every regex special character.

Comment: @AlexHowansky I undertand that `str_replace()` takes arrays.  May point was just that you'd have to explicitly construct the replacement array with each search element, wrapped in the opening and closing tags. Seems tedious to me. To each their own though  :)

Comment: (`array_walk()` would do nicely though, and I'd gladly upvote an answer using it)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to put the regex pattern (including the capturing group) in each item of the array. The way you have it now, you are trying to inject an array into a string, which is likely producing an "Array to string conversion" error.

```
$input = "Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.";

$replaceText = array("/(industry's standard)/", "/(1500s)/", "/(specimen book)/");
$wrapBefore = '<span id="marked">';
$wrapAfter = '</span>';

$output = preg_replace($replaceText, "$wrapBefore$1$wrapAfter", $input);

echo $output;
```

I'm not 100% sure if this is the most efficient way to accomplish this, but it does get what you want (you can add the outer `<div>` tags yourself I assume)

[DEMO](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/8c28bc67663fbabce6f81a2a74adbe72ad9a4e73)

Alternatively, here's a version using `str_replace()` and `array_walk()` (credit for the idea goes to Alex)

```
$input = "Lorem Ipsum has been the industry\'s standard dummy text ever since the 1500s.. to make a type specimen book.";

$searchArray = array("industry's standard", "1500s", "specimen book");
$replacementArray = $searchArray;

$wrapBefore = '<span id="marked">';
$wrapAfter = '</span>';
array_walk($replacementArray, "addWrappers", array($wrapBefore, $wrapAfter));

$output = str_replace($searchArray, $replacementArray, stripslashes($input));

echo $output;

function addWrappers(&$searchTerm, $key, $additionalText)
{
    $searchTerm = $additionalText[0] . $searchTerm . $additionalText[1];
}
```

[DEMO](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/e124b8943143436a8b468e7c71ae5be5801d5850)

Comment: If the database is thus registered: `industry\'s standard` - Then, this process will not work. is not it?

Comment: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/615f18dba5efae846aee584cd724eb820fa79ae4

Comment: @J.Doe You can run `$input` through `stripslashes()` to handle that. You'd have to do the same thing with pretty much any other method of doing this too. You might want to look into why you're storing the slashes in your db records to begin with. `$output = preg_replace($replaceText, "$wrapBefore$1$wrapAfter", stripslashes($input));`

Comment: How can I make the big/small character is unimportant?

Answer (score 1):

Never use regex when you don't have to use regex. `str_replace()` will suit you just fine. There a quite a few ways to get what you're after. The most obvious is simply to call `str_replace()` once for each replacement, continually updating the same output string:

```
$out = $in;
foreach ($words as $word) {
    $out = str_replace($word, '<pre>' . $word . '<post>', $out);
}
```

If you want to get fancy, you can take advantage of the `str_replace()` array feature, and do it all in one shot:

```
$out = str_replace(
    $words,
    array_map(function($word){ return '<pre>' . $word . '<post>'; }, $words),
    $in
);
```

Comment: How can I make the big/small character is unimportant?

Comment: See [`str_ireplace`](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.str-ireplace.php).

Comment: @AlexHowansky Thank you `str_ireplace(array( "", "", ""));` Is it true? If true, not work for me

Comment: @AlexHowansky - Okey I did :) Thank you again Alex